# Can the encoding used to decompress the data automatically in Requests be altered?

Tags: python, encoding, python-requests, gzip

I used `Requests` module in Python, and sent a request and got a response.

The response seems to be `gzip`, given that `r.headers` has the following information:

```
{'Date': 'Tue, 06 Dec 2016 17:35:44 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Content-Length': '21632', 'Cache-Control': 'public,max-age=3600', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding'}
```

However, while `Requests` decides its encoding and returns the decompressed data, when I tried to check out `r.text`, it got `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character XXX`.

Digging it out further, I found that there is one encoding error in the response (`r.content`, which returns the data as `bites`).

```
Currencies":[{"Code":"JPY","Symbol":"\xc2\xa5","ThousandsSeparator":",...
```

However, I'm not sure how I can process the mistakedn encoding error. Even if I set its encoding to `utf-8` (r.encoding = "utf-8"), I still got the `UnicodeEncodeError`. I feel that it was `gzip` that caused its problem which `Requests` proceessed automatically, but how can I correct its wrong yet automatically done decoding?

I sent a request to a SkyScanner's API, with a following code:

```
headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "charset": "utf-8"
}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: @pradyunsg Sorry the title of the question is too misleading and I just edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `requests.Response` object has a raw attribute which allows you to get the raw socket response.

So, you need to do:

```
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, stream=True)
r.raw.read()
```

Source: http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#raw-response-content